# Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to manually move this discussion to chat?

Tags: support, chat

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. **Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?**

OK, fine, but how can I create a chat room on a question when the automatic "move-to-chat" mechanism doesn't work?

Comment: Normally, when you click on the link, the chatroom should be automatically created. What happens when you click the link?

Comment: @DanielFischer no no I mean how to do when the link doesn't appear?

Comment: Then you can a) wait a bit longer, maybe the link appears after the next comment, or b) manually create a chatroom and post a comment with a link to it - which however doesn't move the comments from the thread to the room, or c) politely request that a moderator moves the thread to chat. If not too many people do c), the request will very likely be granted.

Comment: Or you can also copy the comments one by one. Although they will not look like messages in chat, but something [like this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26731325#26731325). (But even in this form they still can be useful to give some context for the conversation in chat.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm pretty sure that I've waited long enough ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585280#comment3269645_1585280)). The problem might be that I click the create-chat-room-button already once before. Or is it that the discussion runs between Will and me on Quiaochu's post? Anyway I think that there is something like a script running when you click the proposed link, to create a chat room. Is it possible to run this script-like thing manually?otherwise I'll go with c, if necessary

Comment: It's probably indeed that you already created [a chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33340/discussion-between-draks-and-qiaochu-yuan) there. If there already is a chatroom for a comment thread, I don't think the system offers to create a second one automatically. That room is now frozen, and the comment with the link is deleted. Since there hasn't been any activity for a couple of days, I'm not sure whether it's worth unfreezing the existing room or creating a new one.

Comment: @DanielFischer no, don't unfreeze this one. The discussion was never continued... But if the comment with the link to the chat is deleted, the chat is quite unreachable. What about having "chat" on the same level like "edit"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Adding a link to the chatroom to the answer next to the "edit" etc. links when a discussion is moved to chat?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes...

Comment: I would guess such a feature request would be [meta-tag:status-declined], since it would be considered too much work for too little benefit. But you could try.